# HTML: Усечение дочернего раздела родительским

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, народ! Недавно потребовалось свелосипедить свой кастомный элемент Select на Vue(Quasar). И случился куръёз, который даже не знаю как грамотно загуглить:

[image: список продолжается там внизу, но нижний край усечён]

Если посмотреть в элементах, то вот он список:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос: какие свойства родительского контейнера могут создать такую ситуацию?

К сожалению сгенерированный HTML слишком тяжелый: куча всяких классов что у формы, что у списка. Поэтому пока решил не вставлять.

Comment: может на белом блоке установленно св-во overflow: hidden;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что на белом родительском блоке установленно св-во [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), которое обрезает содержимое.